# Getting boundary coordinates from given lat,long and radius

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, boundaries

I have:

```
lat-long : (41.8719 , 12.5674 ) 

Radius: 50 meters
```

I want all the boundary coordinates from that given point.

I would like some **scala code** for this.

Comment: [Sheryl Brooke](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127232/sheryl-brooke), what is your approach/method so far? Can you show us please any code that you have written? By the way, are you limited in the number of boundary coordinates, do you any requirement, e.g. precision, density etc.

Comment: @Taras Dubrava No limit of number of boundary coordinates.all possible boundary coordinates i need.it depends on the distance between one boundary coordinate and the other one. minimum decision between the boundary coordinates i m expecting is to have 1meter. i have just calculated the nearby coordinates from that point.but still not able to find boundary coordinates

Comment: This is a variant of the first [geodetic problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems), which you would need to solve *n* times, with bearings wrapping 0 to 2pi, and an interval based on the desired resolution around the perimeter, to construct a circle. Research will show scores of libraries which implement this (with wildly varying accuracy). You may need to port open source code to your chosen language.